# WebApi project deployed at Azure on Linux OS wont find routes

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I was following [this](https://medium.com/@bharatdwarkani/how-to-publish-asp-net-core-3-0-app-in-azure-linux-app-service-explained-from-scratch-6e45392ca256) tutorial about "How to deploy a WebApi on Azure with Linux", the tutorial is targeted to .NET Core 3.1 but in my case its the 2.1. Everything went right except, it won't find any routes. I have a test route and I get notfound.

"//mywebapi.azurewebsites.com/api/Test/Test" doesn't get anything.

Inside of the Program Class, I enabled the Error options to show anything wrong with but still.

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .CaptureStartupErrors(true) // the default
       .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

[image]

> Update!

I was able to read the logs and I get this :

> 2020-03-12 05:23:43.022 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
>   Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
>   2020-03-12 05:23:44.322 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container com_0_3b90f319 for site com
>   2020-03-12 05:23:46.590 ERROR - Container com_0_3b90f319 for site com has exited, failing site start
>   2020-03-12 05:23:46.593 ERROR - Container com_0_3b90f319 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
>   2020-03-12 05:23:46.608 INFO  - Stoping site com because it failed during startup.

and

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` from the Startup.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use publish profile to deploy webapi, click `App Service Linux` and then `import your profile`.

[image]

Remember set `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM` as  `false` in App service Configuration.

BTW, the easiest way is in visual studio, right click your project and choose `Publish`. Click `App Service Linux` and `create New`, set up your app service configuration and it will work well.